AWS SAM in container times out even after setting SAM_CLI_CONTAINER_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT
I'm attempting to containerize the aws sam cli and have read that rather than have a dind situation which seems tricky, it is better to mount docker that running on the host (osx in my case) via /var/run/docker.sock
This works in that I can successfully spin up the container and a mak a call to http://127.0.0.1:5432/hello which hits the container, but the container's log gives an error:
  Timed out while attempting to establish a connection  
  sam_api_test | to the container. You can increase this timeout by setting the                  
  sam_api_test | SAM_CLI_CONTAINER_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT environment variable. The current timeout  
  sam_api_test | is 20.0 (seconds).                                                              
  sam_api_test | 2024-04-19 13:45:53,656 | Invalid lambda response received: Lambda response must
  sam_api_test | be valid json      

  

I'm using the aws hello-world api sample out of the box, so I'm fairly sure it is not a code issue.
I've also tried setting the SAM_CLI_CONTAINER_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT as suggested by adding the env var to the docker-compose file
  environment:
    - SAM_CLI_CONTAINER_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT=120

this does not work and returns the same error and suggestion
/var/task:ro,delegated, inside runtime container                                
2024-04-19 15:27:02,253 | [Container state] OOMKilled False                     
2024-04-19 15:27:02,732 | Cleaning all decompressed code dirs                   
2024-04-19 15:27:02,734 | Timed out while attempting to establish a connection  
to the container. You can increase this timeout by setting the                  
SAM_CLI_CONTAINER_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT environment variable. The current timeout  
is 120.0 (seconds). 

docker-compose.yml:
  services:    
    sam-api:
      build:
        context: ./
        dockerfile: sam-api.Dockerfile
      container_name: sam_api_test
      working_dir: /usr/src/app    
      ports:
        - "5432:5432"
      volumes:
        - ./sam-api-test:/usr/src/app
        - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      restart: "no"
      tty: true
      entrypoint: sam local start-api --host 0.0.0.0 --port 5432 --profile default --debug
      networks:
        - "sam-api-test-network" 

  networks:
    sam-api-test-network:
      name: sam_api_test_network
      driver: bridge

sam-api.Dockerfile:
  FROM node:latest
  RUN npm install -g npm@10.5.2
  # Install AWS CLI
  RUN apt-get update && \
      apt-get install -y awscli && \
      apt-get clean
  # Install AWS SAM CLI
  # RUN npm install -g aws-sam-cli
  RUN curl -L https://github.com/aws/aws-sam-cli/releases/latest/download/aws-sam-cli-linux-x86_64.zip -o aws-sam-cli-linux-x86_64.zip
  RUN unzip aws-sam-cli-linux-x86_64.zip -d sam-installation
  RUN ./sam-installation/install
  # Install Nano
  RUN apt-get install -y nano && \
  apt-get clean
  # Create symbolic links for AWS CLI and AWS SAM CLI
  RUN ln -s /usr/local/bin/aws aws && \
      ln -s /usr/local/bin/sam sam
  # Set the working directory
  WORKDIR /usr/src/app
  # Copy the application files
  COPY . .
  EXPOSE 5432
  # Set the entry point
  CMD ["/bin/sh"]


Did you figure this out? Same issue.

@MattParrilla unfortunately, no

I expect you've probably moved on by now, but I experienced this issue today, and here is my process for solving it. This is what worked for me, but by the look of things, this may be one of those "your mileage may vary" kind of solutions.
TL;DR: Create a script which can be run inside the DinD container to start SAM local with the appropriate hosts:
#!/bin/bash

sam local start-api \
  --host 0.0.0.0 \
  --container-host $(printf "%d.%d.%d.%d" $(awk '$2 == 00000000 && $7 == 00000000 { for (i = 8; i >= 2; i=i-2) { print "0x" substr($3, i-1, 2) } }' /proc/net/route)) \
  --container-host-interface 0.0.0.0

You can then use this as your Dockerfile or docker-compose command, ex CMD [ "bash", ".scripts/run-sam.sh" ]
Long version:
The two problems that contributed to the issue for me were:

SAM handler containers are bound to 127.0.0.1 on the host, which means that your DinD SAM container can't access them, and
Your DinD SAM container doesn't know where the host is that actually hosts those containers.

The first step is to get SAM CLI to bind the handler containers to 0.0.0.0. Add --container-host-interface 0.0.0.0 to the SAM command. Whereas before docker ps might show something like:
6bfb28c421ca   public.ecr.aws/lambda/nodejs:20-rapid-x86_64   "/var/rapid/aws-lamb…"   6 minutes ago   Up 6 minutes    127.0.0.1:7222->8080/tcp                              sad_brattain

you'd now end up with something like:
2b784ce43610   public.ecr.aws/lambda/nodejs:20-rapid-x86_64   "/var/rapid/aws-lamb…"   2 minutes ago    Up 2 minutes            0.0.0.0:5953->8080/tcp                                funny_hopper

Note the change from 127.0.0.1 to 0.0.0.0 in the ports column.
The second step is to tell SAM where the Docker host is. Yes, you've already bound the socket, but we need to tell SAM where to send HTTP requests. We need to set --container-host, but host.docker.internal won't work here it seems, at least not in my experience. There are a number of solutions available here, but I'm aiming for one that is hopefully available just about anywhere:
printf "%d.%d.%d.%d" $(awk '$2 == 00000000 && $7 == 00000000 { for (i = 8; i >= 2; i=i-2) { print "0x" substr($3, i-1, 2) } }' /proc/net/route)

Credit for the above.
Now, of course you can't add the above command for getting the gateway address to the Dockerfile or docker-compose. You'll need to wrap this up in a script, which you can invoke inside the DinD container, for ex:
#!/bin/bash

sam local start-api \
  --host 0.0.0.0 \
  --container-host $(printf "%d.%d.%d.%d" $(awk '$2 == 00000000 && $7 == 00000000 { for (i = 8; i >= 2; i=i-2) { print "0x" substr($3, i-1, 2) } }' /proc/net/route)) \
  --container-host-interface 0.0.0.0

Failing to mount sources into function container
A followup issue you may have is SAM failing to mount your handler sources into the function containers properly. A cheap fix for me was to add something like HOST_SAM_BUILD_DIR=$PWD/.aws-sam/build to the docker-compose service environment (assuming you're using Compose), adding $PWD:$PWD to the volumes, and adding --docker-volume-basedir $HOST_SAM_BUILD_DIR to your SAM script:
#!/bin/bash

sam local start-api \
  --beta-features \
  --host 0.0.0.0 \
  --warm-containers eager \
  --container-host $(printf "%d.%d.%d.%d" $(awk '$2 == 00000000 && $7 == 00000000 { for (i = 8; i >= 2; i=i-2) { print "0x" substr($3, i-1, 2) } }' /proc/net/route)) \
  --container-host-interface 0.0.0.0 \
  --docker-volume-basedir $HOST_SAM_BUILD_DIR

